# Switch currency based on custom customer attribute

Tags: ce-1.9.2.4, multicurrency

If all my customers had a custom field containing either 'GBP' or 'EURO' for example, is it possible for the store to switch currency based on this custom field value once they login?

So EURO customers see Euro pricing, and GBP see GBP pricing.

Comment: use : Mage::app()->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode('USD');
Mage::app()->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode('GBP'); base on condition

Answer (score 1):

You can define an observer on `controller_action_layout_render_before` and have something like this:

```
function controllerActionLayoutRenderBefore($observer)
{ 
    if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) return;

    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $currency = $customer->getData('my_currency_attribute');

    if (!empty($currency))
       Mage::app()->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode($currency); 
}
```

Given that the value of your attribute matches EXACTLY the available currency codes (in your example it should `EUR` instead of `EURO`)